# label does not contain location property

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I use a loop to create multiple labels using VB.NET. Currently, I want to change the labels position horizontally, but the `label1.location` is not working at all. It shows an error saying:

> location is not member of label.

The same happens with the caption property. It's WebForms application (visual studio 2015).

```
Sub countTable()
    Dim _dt As New DataTable
    fromdt = Me.fromdate.Text
    todt = Me.todate.Text
    model_no = Me.modelno.SelectedValue
    ' defect = Me.defectcode.SelectedValue

    gradeee = ""
    For Each item As ListItem In ll.Items
        If item.Selected Then
            gradeee += "'" & item.Text & "',"
            'message += item.Text + " " + item.Value + "\n"
        End If
    Next
    gradeee += "'test'"

    defect = Me.defectcode.SelectedValue
    classifi = ""
    For Each item As ListItem In mm.Items
        If item.Selected Then
            classifi += "'" & item.Text & "',"
            'message += item.Text + " " + item.Value + "\n"
        End If
    Next
    classifi += "'test'"
    'Me.Label1.Text = classifi

    _sql = " SELECT distinct TO_CHAR(S.TEST_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD') AS period "
    _sql += " FROM CELLINT.CELL_TEST T "
    _sql += " LEFT OUTER JOIN CELLINT.CELL_TEST_YIELD S  "
    _sql += " ON S.SHEET_ID = T.SHEET_ID "
    _sql += " and S.TEST_TIME between to_date('" & fromdt & "','YYYY/MM/DD') and to_date('" & todt & "','YYYY/MM/DD') "
    If model_no <> "All" Then
        _sql += " and S.model_no = '" & model_no & "'"
    End If
    _sql += " and T.defect_code_desc || '(' || T.defect_code ||')'  = '" & defect & "'"

    If classifi.Contains("All") = True Then

    Else
        _sql += " and s.class in (" & classifi & ") "
        '_sql += " and class = '" & classifi & "' "
    End If
    If gradeee.Contains("All") = True Then

    Else
        _sql += " and t.grade in (" & gradeee & ") "
        '_sql += " and class = '" & classifi & "' "
    End If
    _sql += " order by TO_CHAR(S.TEST_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD') asc "
    ' Response.Write(_sql)
    _dt = CIMDatabaseLink_USR.GetDataTable(_sql)

    count = _dt.Rows.Count - 1
    'Response.Write(_dt.Rows.Count - 1)

    For i = 0 To count
        Dim returnHTML As String = ""
        Dim myLabel As Label = New Label()

        period = "" & _dt.Rows(i).Item("period").ToString() & ""
        returnHTML = "<table><tr>"
        returnHTML = returnHTML & "<td><div>" & ReturnTable(period) & "</div><td>"
        returnHTML = returnHTML & "</tr></table>"

        myLabel.ID = "Label" & i & ""
        ' myLabel.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(ReturnTable(period))
        myLabel.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(returnHTML)
        myLabel.Location = New Point(7, 10)

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myLabel)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Chris, welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us your code so we can help you with it. Here are some topics that would help you refine your question: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's not enough information here to help.  You need to provide much more information.  Project type.  Code that is causing the error.  Anything else of relevance.

Comment: myLabel.ID = "Label" & i & ""
           
            myLabel.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(returnHTML)
            myLabel.Location = New Point(7, 10)

Comment: It shows error at myLabel.location

Comment: @ChrisYQ Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52268031/edit) your question and include your code there (make sure it's properly formatted), and also mention the project type (WinForms, WPF, WebForms, etc.).

Comment: Please help. Thanks .

Comment: WebForms controls don't have `Location` properties like WinForms does. You've got to set `top` and `left` through CSS, as well as an appropriate value for [`position`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: same error. shows that top is not member of label.

Comment: @ChrisYQ, `through CSS`, not in code

Answer (score 0):

```
myLabel.Style.Add("position" , "absolute")
myLabel.Style.Add("top" , "7px")
myLabel.Style.Add("left" , "10px")
```

Those are just some examples, but try something like that via code-behind to change the style of the label.

You could also use to do them all

```
myLabel.Attributes.Add("style" , "top: 7px; left: 10px; position: absolute;")
```